# Sharing values of a variable enqueued as CL_MEM_READ_WRITE buffer across work-groups in OpenCL

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, shared-memory

I would like to know if there is a way of updating (adding values) to a `__global` input variable (enqueued as a `CL_MEM_READ_WRITE` buffer) across work-groups.

My kernel is something like this:

```
__kernel void func(__global float *y, ...){
    ...
    y[id] += value;
    ...
}
```

The value of `id` may be repeated across different work-groups (i.e., `id` may be equal `2` in a work-item from work-group 1 and in a work-item from, e.g., work-group 4).

Running the kernel like this gives me undefined behavior (different outputs for every run of the kernel).

Does anyone know how to work around this?

I've tried atomic adds (with `atomic_xchg`, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863587/atomic-operations-with-double-opencl)) but nothing changed.

I've also tried adding barriers (with both `CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE` and `CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE`.

There is a similar question to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852478/concurrent-updates-x-a-to-global-memory-in-opencl), but I'm trying to update a variable in global memory with work-items from different work-groups. Apparently, in the mentioned question a variable in global memory is being shared among work-items within the same work-group and the problem is solved with atomic adds.

Edit: as asked in the comments and to try to make things more clear, the results I expect to get a vector (`y`) which is updated by additions from several different work-items spread across several work-groups. And the results I'm getting are partial additions (I know the final result since I've also implemented the algorithm in Matlab and I can see the additions are not complete). To me it seems that the result I'm getting is from the work-group that finished last, without the sharing of the `y` variable across the work-groups.

Hope this has made things clearer.

Comment: What do you mean by "I've tried atomic adds (with `atomic_xchg`) but nothing changes."? Is that a typo? `atomic_xchg` is not suitable for addition. What about `atomic_add`?

Comment: It was not a typo. ```atomic_xchg``` IS suitable for floating point addition (take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863587/atomic-operations-with-double-opencl) ). ```atomic_add``` works only for integer types.

Comment: The addition algorithm you now linked uses `atomic_cmpxchg` not simple xchg. Also perhaps you could provide us with more detail about the results you’re expecting and what you’re actually getting.

Comment: Yes, I saw the part regarding ```atomic_cmpxchg```, but as far as I understood it is used for double precision addition, and I am working with single precision floating points. I will edit the question to try to make things more clear.

Comment: No, xchg and cmpxchg are fundamentally different operations, and can both work on different sized operands.

Comment: I see. I'll look further into it.

Comment: Ok from your updated question it’s clear to me that the problem is the use of atomic_xchg.

Comment: I’ll try to write up a proper answer later, I’m only on my phone right now, but implementing the thread safe addition from the other answer using cmpxchg should work (using uint in place of ulong when using float instead of double)

Comment: @pmdj thank you for your answers! I've implemented the atomic add with cmpxchg (as shown [in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863587/atomic-operations-with-double-opencl) and it worked. Thanks again